# Чем могут быть опасны внешние ключи в БД?

Tags: innodb, key, mysql

Наткнулся на проект, в котором главный разработчик запретил использование внешних ключей в БД (MySql, таблицы InnoDb).
Но не смог понятно объяснить, почему так сделали.
Кроме недостатков, описанных в [документации](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html), может кто-нибудь назвать другие адекватные причины отказа от внешних ключей?

Comment: Тем, что бабе Мане потом бухгалтерию руками будет сложнее сводить?

Comment: А почему-бы у него самого не спросить?

Comment: Может, тем, что вставка и обновление строк будут быстрее (на сколько?) выполняться, т.к. не будет проверки на целостность?

Comment: > Наткнулся на проект, в котором главный разработчик запретил использование внешних ключей в БД (MySql, таблицы InnoDb).

неужели wordpress?

Comment: @Etki
> неужели wordpress?  

Нет, проект на symfony2

@eicto
> А почему-бы у него самого не спросить?

Он в отпуске. А любопытство гложет.

Comment: @zenith, может быть, какой-нибудь новый Законопроект в Думе. А разработчик о нем узнал загодя. И, вообще, до коих пор мы должны слепо следовать за Бойсом и Кодом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Администраторы баз данных часто
> создают такую сложную топологию
> связей, при которой затруднительно, а
> зачастую и вовсе невозможно получить
> резервную копию или восстановить
> единичные таблицы.

Думаю из-за этого, плюс каскадное удаление может потереть здоровенный кусок базы, если "правильно" прописано.